# iPhoto Migrated library

Tags: photos, photos.app, migration

I have a Macbook Air **128 Gb** and its always short on hard disk!
Since Photos app came out, I started using it. I did the initial migration of iPhoto to Photos app (don't know which settings i chose). The issue now is :

I have 2 photo libraries

1. Photo library (35Gb)
2. iPhoto migrarted library (27Gb)

I don't think I've 70gb worth of photos in there and when i try to open the migrated library it says already migrated to photos app. All tools like `whatsize` shows them like different files and even when I copy both in my external hard drive it takes a combined storage of 70Gb. My mac does not have that much data but still only 5 Gb is left.

> Now, is it safe to delete iPhoto migrated library, how can I be double
> sure that no data is lost! I'm in serious need of space.

To make my question unique from [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182792/how-can-i-remove-my-old-iphoto-library-after-migrating-to-photos) , there user's iPhoto and photos app library were taking combined 35Gb, here they are taking 35+27 = 62Gb!
My libraries take individual space, so please don't mix this question with the other one, it doesn't answer my question!

[image]

1st one is with photo library and other one is with iPhoto!

Comment: They are different scenarios !

Comment: Can you please verify your assumption regarding space duplication (see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181202/does-migrating-to-apples-new-photos-app-actually-double-my-storage-requirements)? Even though the libraries seem to take twice the space, they should physically contain the same JPG files (which all get counted twice). Copying both libraries *will* break the link on the files and really result in double space, but on your SSD this should not be the case.

Comment: To verify, right-click the (new) Photos Library in Finder, select "Show package content", open Masters and than a folder older than 2015 (all the way down till you get an individual picture. Then open Terminal, type `ls -l` followed by a space character and then drag/drop the picture from before onto the Terminal window (which should include the full path of the picture). Then press enter and add the output you get either to the question or as a comment.

Comment: updated my post with screenshot

Comment: Thanks. The number right in front of your user name (taran) is the number of links/references to the picture file. It is 2 in your case which means that both directory entries point to the *same* picture on disk. Which also means that you can safely delete the old library *but* unfortunately you will not gain a lot of space.